# Remover elementos assinalados na checkbox (JAVAScript, PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de cadastro de automóveis no qual preciso alterar meu botão de exclusão que era gerado para cada novo veículo cadastrado por checkbox para que mais de um elemento possa ser deletado, alterei o valor do input para checkbox e já adaptei as funções em Javascript e PHP mas não consegui uma alteração que enviei para o botão de exclusão no menu os id's dos produtos a serem cadastrados, alguém poderia em apontar uma direção para fazer isso? Segue o código:
PHP/HTML:

```
    while( $exibe = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        "<h3>"; 
    echo "<tr  class=''; style='cellpadding:none;'id_automovel= (" . $exibe['id'] . ") >";
    echo"<td> <input type='checkbox' onClick='removerLinha(this)' id='delete' name='deleta[]' class='button'></td>";

    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['descricao']. "</td>" ;
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['placa']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['codigoRenavam']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['anoModelo']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['anoFabricacao']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['cor']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['km']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['marca']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['preco']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['precoFipe']. "";
    "</h3>";
    "</tr>";
}
<div class="box-side">
<h3>Ações</h3>
<ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><input class="btn-add" value="Incluir" type="button"     onClick="window.open('http://localhost/teste/templates/form.automovel.php')"     id="cd"></li> 
<li><input type="button" value="Imprimir" id="imp"></li>
<li><input type="button" value="Excluir" id="ex"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function removerLinha(dados){
var exclusao = $(dados).parent().parent().attr('id_automovel');
request = $.ajax({
    url: "/teste/services/automoveis.service.php?m=exclui", //excluir.php
    type: "post",
    data: "id=" + exclusao 
});

request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    window.location.reload();
});

request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.error(
        "The following error occurred: "+
        textStatus, errorThrown
    );
});
};
```

PHP:

```
function removerLinha(){
$vari = $_POST['id'];
$conexao = conecta();
$sql= 'DELETE FROM automovel WHERE id =' . $vari . ' LIMIT 50';
mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
}
```

---

### Edit para a forma que funcionou caso ajude alguém:

PHP/HTML:

```
    while( $exibe = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        "<h3>"; 
    echo "<tr  class=''; style='cellpadding:none;'id_automovel= (" . $exibe['id'] . ") >";
    echo"<td> <input type='checkbox' class='checkform' id='delete' value= " . $exibe['id'] . " class='button'></td>";

    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['descricao']. "</td>" ;
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['placa']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['codigoRenavam']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['anoModelo']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['anoFabricacao']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['cor']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['km']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['marca']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['preco']. "";
    echo " <td onClick =editaLinha(" . $exibe['id'] . ")>" .$exibe['precoFipe']. "";
    "</h3>";
    "</tr>";
}
```

JS:

```
function removerLinha(dados){
var exclusao = [];
console.log(exclusao);
$(".checkform:checked").each(function(){ 
    exclusao.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(exclusao);
request = $.ajax({ url: "/teste/services/automoveis.service.php?m=exclui", //excluir.php
    type: "post",
    data: "id=" + exclusao 
});

request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    window.location.reload();
    console.log(response);
});

request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.error(
        "The following error occurred: "+
        textStatus, errorThrown
    );
});
};
```

PHP:

```
function removerLinha(){
$vari = $_POST['id'];
$vari = explode( ',' , $vari);
print_r($vari);

$conexao = conecta();
$sql= 'DELETE FROM automovel WHERE id =' . $vari;
mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
}
```

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc precisará definir o name do checkbox como um array, exemplo

```
<input type="checkbox" name="carro[]" value="idDoCarro" />
```

Do lado PHP, basta percorrer o então array do post/get $_POST['carro'] e deletar os valores

Edição:

Não vi o trecho em ajax, sugiro criar uma nova função e chamá-la no onclick em outra separada das linhas, já que a remoção é em grupo:

```
function removerLinhas(dados){
var exclusao = { 'carro[]' : []};
$(":checked").each(function() {
  data['carro[]'].push($(this).val());
});
request = $.ajax({
    url: "/teste/services/automoveis.service.php?m=exclui", //excluir.php
    type: "post",
    data: exclusao 
});
```

Comment: Então, o name já está em Array, o problema está em chamar a função com o botão de exclusão, em vez de excluir assim que a checkbox é marcada, mas até agora tudo o q eu tentei não funcionou e não tenho ideia de qual seja a forma correta =(

Comment: Veja agora, amigo

Comment: Obrigada, me ajudou, irei editar a pergunta da forma que funcionou :)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, eu acredito que a nova classe PDO do php seja mais organizado visualmente para a manipulação de dados.

Na inserção do banco de dados para inputs do tipo checkbox, é necessário criar uma coluna para cada tipo selecionada, sendo 0 para não selecionada ou 1 para selecionada.

Na hora da listagem do banco para o html, somente verificar se o valor teve 0 ou 1 e assim manipulá-las.